# Accessing model subclass attributes with django tastypie

Tags: django, subclass, tastypie

I have a model that is sublcassed

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    child_model = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Bar(Foo):
    woots = models.ManyToManyField(Woot)

class Woot(models.Model):
    color = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

And some tastypie resources:

```
class FooResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Foo.objects.all()

class BarResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Foo.objects.all()

class WootResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Woot.objects.all()
```

When accessing the FooResource, I'd ideally like it to 'reroute' and return a BarResource instead if the child_model attribute == bar.

If I can't do that, then any way that I can get an array of woots serialized and into the bundle (when child_model attribute == bar) would be fine by me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
class FooResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Foo.objects.all()  

    def dehydrate(self, bundle):
        if bundle.data['child_model']=="bar":
            return json.loads(BarResource().dispatch_list(bundle.request).content)
        return bundle
```

Comment: Nope.  Didn't work.  WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'request'.  If I change bundle.request to bundle, it returns a bunch of unserialized Bar objects.  I'm thinking maybe I need to build the bundle first but my attempts to do that thus far have failed.

Comment: I don't think bundle is a WSGIRequest. bundle.x should give an error : Bundle object has no.....
You might be doing this: bundle.request.request ? or maybe did you override the obj_get_list method in your resource which tries to access the request attr of the request object?

Comment: Have you tried it and gotten it to work? I copied your code exactly and that's the error I got.  obj_get_list takes a bundle, but you're sending it bundle.request, which is a WSGIRequest.

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly fine with my api. According to the docs obj_get_list takes a request  : http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/non_orm_data_sources.html
What version are you using BTW ?

Comment: 0.9.14.  Is it different for ORM vs non ORM?  https://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html?highlight=obj_get_list shows obj_get_list taking bundle, not request, which is inline with my results

Comment: Ah yes, it does work differently for ModelResource than Resource. I've update the answer, it may not be the ideal solution but it works :)

Comment: Upvote because it works.  Leaving it unchecked for now though because it's too slow to use in production.  Goes from milliseconds to 10 seconds to load.

Comment: try this : 
return BarResource().get_list(bundle.request).content